# Merge array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have 2 arrays to merge. The first array is multidimensional, and the second array is a single array:

```
$a = array(
    array('id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Mike'),
    array('id'=>'2', 'name'=>'Lina'),
);

$b = array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Niken');
```

How to merge 2 arrays to have same array depth?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you want is this:

```
array(
    array('id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Mike'),
    array('id'=>'2', 'name'=>'Lina'),
    array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Niken')
)
```

You can just add the second as a new element to the first:

```
$one[] = $two;
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought

Answer (score 1):

Just append the second array with an empty dimension operator.

```
$one = array(
    array('id'=>'1', 'name'=>'Mike'),
    array('id'=>'2', 'name'=>'Lina')
);

$two = array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Niken');

$one[] = $two;
```

But if you're wanting to merge unique items, you'll need to do something like this:

```
if(false === array_search($two, $one)){
    $one[] = $two;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with the array push with the current array, i modified your code so it would work

```
<?php
  $myArray = array(
    array('id' => '1',  'name' => 'Mike'),
    array('id' => '2',  'name '=> 'Lina')
  );
  array_push($myArray, array('id'=>'3', 'name'=>'Niken'));
  // Now $myArray has all three of the arrays
  var_dump($myArray);
?>
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

For inserting anything into array you can just use push over [index](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ($array[] = $anything;) or [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function. Your case can use both approaches.